# ScrollView Hide UIButton and UiWebView in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

It is an old non-ARC projects in xib's and i am trying to add **UIButton** and **UIWebview** inside **scroll view**, but when i run the code, the button and webview are not visible.

[image]

I tried to print the frame of button

```
NSLog(@"btnMore frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(btnMore.frame));
```

Getting value

```
btnMore frame = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Comment: can you show some additional code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am just dragging elements in xibs like previous elements which r visible at run time. now i m adding more objects like button and web view. what u need to see

Comment: sorry , i dont know constraints

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry i cant get u

Comment: sorry - the problem occur is related to constraints, I dont know constraints

Comment: @Imran Where you are printing its frame? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @AshishKakkad in viewWillAppear

Comment: print in viewdidappear , you get original frames

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik btnMore frame = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}  how can i update and show

Answer (score -1):

Print frame in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews and update your constraint.

Comment: no issue still remains i tried by adding in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: no need of down it, I am just provide you suggestion for check constraint if those are added on you button(update your constraint,we don't know your added constraint) or also check once your button is not hidden in xib

Comment: you can use comment plz for one line info as others r doing

Comment: Apologies for that buddy but I am not able to comment on that now, it need 50 point for comment